# Can't align items vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I'm trying to align a chevron arrow in the center of my screen using flexbox and bootstrap but whenever I try to use `align-self: center;` or `align-content: center;` it doesn't do anything, my arrow just align's itself horizontally and not vertically, Would you guys have any short way to achieve what I am trying to do using flexbox?

Here is my code:

```css
html
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: white;
}

#arrow
{
color: grey;
font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<i id="arrow" class="fas fa-chevron-down d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center"></i>
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap it inside a div and then align the contents of that div to center?

Comment: @Areg yes but it doesn't work, I did this `<div class="d-flex align-content-center">
<i id="arrow" class="fas fa-chevron-down my-auto"></i> 
</div>`

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 I don't think so, I really want a simple way to do it. I don't want to wrap a single arrow in 5 containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good you already tried a `div` container, but you also have to make sure the container has a certain size:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

#arrow-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#arrow {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="arrow-container">
  <i id="arrow" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** You don't even need the Bootstrap flex classes, then. By the way, you don't need `position: absolute;` on the container or use `vw` and `vh` as units. I just added it because you wanted to center on screen.

Comment: Super cool!, it works like a charm, thanks. I have another quick question, If I wanted to achieve the same thing with margins how would it go, would I have to do `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let me add an example.

Comment: I promised too much. You are right, you can generally use `margin: auto` for that, but I couldn't get it to work in your snippet. Who knows why...

Comment: Oh ok no worries, thank you for trying anyway. If I used margin: auto; which position should I choose to make it work?

Comment: Well, the different ways of doing this are [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-to-vertical-align-elements-in-a-div)

Answer (score -2):

For some reason, `%` never worked for me. So I'm using this [one](https://codepen.io/ptheodosiou/pen/eYYBqBg)

Comment: Thanks for the response but what do you mean with the `%`?

Comment: @Alex I wanted to say that when I use `html { height: 100% } body{ height:100% }` my code never worked correctly. There was something that was broken...

Comment: Oh ok, so what should I do with the html and body, should I remove the height and width properties? @ThPadelis

Comment: If you go with my answer, then there is no need to use them. Otherwise, the [selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58483321/10165585) answer is what you need. @Alex

Comment: Ok, btw would you know why when I use both ways my webpage height is slightly bigger and a scrollbar appears at the right? @ThPadelis

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, it should remove unwanted margins from the body. But if you have extra items in your body, like a `navbar` for example, then you need to calculate the diff of the body. For example let's say that you have a `navbar` with height of `90px`, then your body should have `height: calc(100vh -  90px)`. @Alex

Comment: Oh ok, thats exactly what I have, thank you I'll keep it in mind :D